# java - JTable setValueAt not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm doing a chess game and I need to make a log table that prints every move. The LogTable class is like this:

```
public class LogTable {
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    private JTable table;
    public LogTable(JPanel panel){
        String[] columnNames = {"Move No.",
                                "White",
                                "Black"};

        model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
        table = new JTable();
        //model.isCellEditable(i, i1)
        table.setModel(model);

        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);

        //Create the scroll pane and add the table to it.
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        panel.add(scrollPane);
    }

    public void newMove(chessPiece piece){
        if (piece.getColor() == 0){
            Object[] newRow = new Object[3];
            newRow[0] = model.getRowCount()+1;
            newRow[1] = piece.sayPos();
            newRow[2] = " ";
            model.addRow(newRow);
        }
        else {
            model.setValueAt(piece.sayPos(), model.getRowCount(), model.getColumnCount());
        }
    }
}
```

But in the first black move it thows an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. The newMove function is called at the chessPiece class:

```
public void move(int newX, int newY, JPanelSquare jPanelSquareGrid[][], LogTable logTable){
    resetShowValidMoves(jPanelSquareGrid);
    logTable.newMove(this);
}
```

The rest of the move code is in each piece, which call super. I'm using the DefaultTableModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) :

```
public DefaultTableModel(Object[] columnNames,int rowCount)
```

> Constructs a DefaultTableModel with as many columns as there are elements in
>   columnNames and rowCount of null object values. Each column's name
>   will be taken from the columnNames array.

You instantiate the DefaultTableModel with 0 rows. So you can't set the value of an item in row 0 since it doesn't exist.

Comment: true but the first move, that the white does, always add a new row. But anyways, I ended up finding the error. getRowCount() and getColumnCount() return values starting at 1, but for the index use at setValueAt I needed to use from 0, so I just subtracted 1 from them.